# "Useless expression" warning which I think is not correct

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Consider following code sample:

```
def cleanUpAdvertiserInAdtech(name: String)(implicit driver: WebDriver):Unit = {
    AdtechLoginPage.open
    AdtechLoginPage.login
    val attempt = Try {
      AdtechDashboardPage.openAdvertisers
      AdtechAdvertisersPage.deleteAdvertiserIfExists(name)
    }
    AdtechAdvertisersPage.logout
    attempt.get
  }
```

IntelliJ IDEA underlines the last line `attempt.get` and says that this is a useless expression. I am not sure I understand exactly why because this line just returns `Unit` in case when everything was nice in the `Try{...}` but throws an exception when something went wrong there.
Could you explain?

Comment: `Try[Unit].get` will only return Unit if the Try was a success if it was a Failure instead it will throw an exception. You could just as well leave out the `Try { }`  in that case. Why do you do the get anyway?

Comment: @DominicEgger, precisely, I know the semantics of `Try.get`. In case you did not notice there is one more line between `Try{...}` and `attempt.get` where logout is made. So I could not leave out the `Try{}` as you've suggested. So returning to my original question, why "useless expression" warning?

Comment: Why not `try {...} finally {...}`?

Comment: @Evgeny, I was not asking how can this code be modified. I do see it is analog of try{...} catch{...} finally{...} but my question was about particular warning.

Comment: I tried to point, that with `try-finally` you do not need this `get` call (and looks clear for possible maintainer that code is about `logout` after action before leaving method either successfully or with `Exception`). Intellij sees that you try to return something where expected nothing and notify you. `Try.get` does not announce exception throwing (except of comment), so I do not think that intellij can even assume exception here.. From this point of view last expression is redundant for Intellij

Comment: sorry what I meant out to say is just leave out `attempt.get` it does effectively nothing beyond possibly throwing an exception. if you want to handle the error case of your `Try` consider returning the `Try` instance

Answer (score 1):

Because `attempt.get` not only will return **Success** value, it also will throw **Failure** exception:

- If the `Try.get` return success value, `attempt.get` will return a **success** value, but it's never used. so this warning is correct to throw.
- If the `Try.get` is failed,`attempt.get` will throw an `Exception`, the **IDE** warning is useless.

So I think **IDE** is correct to highlight this warning(**IDE** doesn't know whether will fail). you should change the `Exception` evaluate style, like use: `match` or `try catch finally`.

Comment: I was just experimenting on how to do try/catch/finally without these constructs. `catch` with partial function inside looks sometimes bit too verbose for me, so I think `Try{..}.get` is a good way to achieve one particular thing: throw any exception that happened in the `Try{...}` block. So it does look to me that in IDE warning is misleading here. I don't have anything against try/catch/finally, but it's not the only option to work with.

Comment: So to recap, before asking I was completely understanding the things you have written in your answer. I just do not agree with the warning of IntelliJ that this expression is useless. It in fact has a particular useful purpose.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar, So you actually need is:`attempt match {
      case Failure(e) => throw e
    }`, and don't care the **return value**.

Comment: ok, but for `get` method actually will return **value** if `Success`, so **IDE** should highlight it, like: you have declared a variable and never use it. the **IDE** or other tools(like findbugs) should highlight you have an unused variable. right?

Comment: exactly:if I would have declared that as a variable - I would not complain. But I am not declaring a variable. I have a computation of type `Try[Unit]` and I just extract the result of this computation and return it or exception is thrown if the computation failed. And `Unit` for me is not "nothing" but a normal result. So I think `attemp.get` is much less verbose in this case than `attempt match { case Failure(e) => throw e }`, don't you think so? :)

Comment: So you need your own `get`  like: `throwIfFail` method for your case :), not use `get`, since you not care the **Success** value.

Comment: and another thing also need to call out, `Try` and `Option` actually we think it as a **Monad**, often we use with `map` and `flatMap` to handle **side effect**(like `Exception` in your example).

Comment: I would correct you here: to handle "side effect" we use `foreach` in monads.